# Generic Error Handling Angular 14 - throwError deprecated

Tags: angular

So in an earlier version of Angular I had a generic CRUD service and this worked fine:

```
 deleteById<T>(id: any, apiMethod: string): Observable<T> {

    let callPoint = this.endpoint.concat('/', apiMethod, '/', id);

    return this.httpClient.delete<T>(callPoint, this.httpHeader)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.processError)
      )
  }

  processError(err: { error: { message: string; }; status: any; message: any; }) {
    let message = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      message = err.error.message;
    } else {
      message = `Error Code: ${err.status}\nMessage: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.log(message);
    return throwError(message);
  }
```

I now recieve a warning against the `return throwError(message);` line of processError stating that throwError is deprecated.

If I change this line to:

`return new Error(message);`

I then get errors against my catchError call in my deleteById method. The catchError now does not like that I am passing `this.processError`.

I've been scouring the internet, but cannot find any good examples of how I might be able to change this.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656760/3528396

Comment: Does this answer your question? [throwError(error) is now deprecated, but there is no new Error(HttpErrorResponse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655492/throwerrorerror-is-now-deprecated-but-there-is-no-new-errorhttperrorresponse)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions, however they use `throwError` which is the problem I'm trying to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly with the RxJs documentation the `throwError` function uses a function as a parameter.

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError

So what you should do is the following.

```
processError(err: any) { 
  let message = '';
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    message = err.error.message;
  } else {
    message = `Error Code: ${err.status}\nMessage: ${err.message}`;
  }
  console.log(message);
  return throwError(() => new Error(message)); // use throwError from the rxjs package
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes, this is interesting. If I just change the retrun line as per your example. The error disappears, what I dont understand is why am I not getting `throwError` deprecated any more, since I am still using it on this line. However, I will look to moving this to an interceptor, which is where it should really be, but at least this get's me past my initial problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you see the RxJs documentation the method that pases the error is deprecated, but the one that you send a function as a parameter is not. Probably is some background of why that was deprecated and they change for this method, but I dont really have that answer. Adding RxJs Doc link in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an `ErrorInterceptor` service to implement the `generic error handling` in your project.

Please refer below code:

```
/* all required imports go here */
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                retry(1),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errorMessage = '';
                    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                        // client-side error
                        errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                    } else {
                        // server-side error
                        errorMessage = `Error Status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
                    }
                   console.log(errorMessage);
                   return throwError(() => {
                        return errorMessage;
                   });
                })
            )
    }
}
```

Next, you could import it in your `app.module.js` and use it to handle any kind of errors in your project.